# how to find the nearest signature in a bit Trie, given a bit array?

Tags: java, algorithm, tree, trie

given a Trie of bits, and an input as a bit array/vector, how can I find the nearest neighbor for the input vector in the Trie?

The algorithm that I'm trying to do is the following:
Given a bit vector V and a permutation function F, do the following:

1- F(V) = V_; where V_ is the signature of V.

2- Insert V_ in a trie;

after some time ... given a bit vector U, do the following:

1- F(U) = U_;

2- Find the nearest signature in the trie.

A nearest signature is defined by the hamming distance.

Comment: How are you defining "nearest neighbor?"

Comment: @templatetypedef A nearest signature is defined by the hamming distance.

Comment: Do you have to use a trie here?  There are much better data structures for this.

Comment: @templatetypedef yes, I'm reading a paper and I'm trying to understand why they are doing a step, in order to do so I need to understand that.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Branch and bound](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_and_bound) to successively narrow down the search space. Do a depth-first search on the tree, and keep track of how many bits have miss-matched so far. When you find a leaf that is closer to your target, you update the current cap. When you walk into a subtree that are further than the current cap, you prune it. Always walk into a matching subtree first, if there is one.